# Custom title and image for Facebook share button on AJAX result

Tags: ajax, facebook, image, share, title

This question exists in different flavors, but not for AJAX pages.

I use AJAX to pull a single video into my page and I want a custom FB share button for it.  Everything I've read so far says that FB pulls the required title and image from meta-tags in the page's < head> section (og:image and og:title).

I've tried to change the meta properties when the AJAX call returns, before rendering the share button.  This hasn't worked.  It uses the values that were present upon initial page load.  I have yet to encounter a single answer to this question.

Are there data attributes I can add to the 'fb-like' div to specify a custom title and image (similar to data-href)?

Danke!

Comment: No. You need an individual URL for each individual piece of content that you want to share, and that has to deliver the relevant meta info in the HTML source code it returns. The FB scraper does not “speak” JavaScript.

Comment: I was not aware you could have multiple meta tags with the same property.  Wouldn't there be a scope conflict?  Where would the meta tags go in relation to the 'fb-like' div in the response HTML?  I just tried your suggestion with image and title meta tags right before the 'fb-like' div on each video response, and FB is still fetching the meta info for the main page, not for the specific video.  Thanks.

Comment: _“I was not aware you could have multiple meta tags with the same property”_ – did I say you could? No, I said that for _each_ individual piece of content you want to share, you need an _individual_ URL as well, that will deliver the meta information for that individual piece of content (_only_ for that individual piece of content).

Comment: Care to elaborate syntactically?  How is the meta info parameterized on the unique URL?

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking. `http://example.com/foo` delivers meta data for Open Graph object #1, and `http://example.com/bar` for object #2 – simple as that. What technique you use server-side to accomplish that, is up to you. (Could even be _static files_ if you like.)

Comment: Bear with me, Broe.  This is my first foray into Open Graph.  Server-side, I'm just sending a div of class 'fb-like', whose parameters are data-href, data-share, etc.  What I'm asking you is:  what parameters do I use to specify title and image?  Can you give me a concrete example / snippet?

Comment: You can not specify those with the div that is rendered into the share button – the URL to share is the _only_ parameter. That URL has to deliver meta elements that hold the information. And therefor, you need an individual URL for each single piece of content that you want to share (and that you want to have individual title, description, image etc.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71051/discussion-between-frank-and-cbroe).

Comment: I don’t see much else to discuss here.

Comment: I already have unique "individual" URLs for each shareable item.  They are of the form:

http:www.example.com/?v=vid1

http:www.example.com/?v=vid2

However, the pages corresponding to these URLs don't yet exist at the time the share button is rendered.  They are generated dynamically.  So when you say the URLs have to deliver the meta information, it does not apply to non-existent pages.  What am I missing?

Comment: When a client – such as the FB scraper – requests `http:www.example.com/?v=vid1`, then you render a basic HTML document including the required meta data – where is the problem in that? _“it does not apply to non-existent pages”_ – well, _sharing_ doesn’t apply to things that “don’t exist” either. If you want to share something, then make sure it “exists” when Facebook comes and requests the meta data.

Comment: The FB share meta data for http:www.example.com/?v=vid1 is derived from the dynamic result of this URL, a result that comes from an external API call.

My site uses AJAX.  When it receives the above URL, it actually loads the base URL, then displays a quick notification to the user informing them that vid1 is being fetched.  It then fetches the video using AJAX.  The AJAX call returns only the HTML for the video and share button.

Comment: Again: When the scraper requests `http://www.example.com/?v=vid1` (if that is the URL you want to share), then that URL has to deliver the meta data. How you accomplish that, is up to you. If your data is requested from an external API – then create a server-side script that requests the same data from that API, so that it can deliver the correct meta information to the requesting client.

Comment: You're the man.  Worked nicely.  Your explanation of the mechanics of the scraper sealed the deal.

Comment: OK, glad you got it working. I wrote up a short summary as an answer. (Should that still be missing something that was crucial for your understanding, let me know, then I will edit that in.)

Comment: Minor point regarding wording: I found your reference to metadata having to be "delivered by/under a URL" unclear at first. There is some linguistic ambiguity because it could be understood as metadata parameterized on the URL string itself. It seems elementary now, but other newbies might still find it ambiguous. I would be explicit (as you were on your very first response) and say something like "the HTML page corresponding to the unique URL should include the relevant meta tags in the head section."

I'd also use "unique URL" instead of "individual URL", but that may be a matter of style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an individual URL for each individual piece of content that you want to share. Open Graph objects (and simple shared links “become” such, automatically) are identified by their URL (`og:url`).

Now if your whole page is built on AJAX, you still need to create such individual URLs somehow – the Facebook scraper tool does not “speak” JavaScript, and relies solely on the OG meta information that the server delivers for any URL it requests.

Since the hash part of an URL is only of relevance client-side (and does not even get send to the server), “typical” AJAX URLs that rely on those to tell the client which piece of content to load in the background are no good here.

So if you want to share two pieces of content (videos) as `http://www.example.com/?v=vid1` and `http://www.example.com/?v=vid2`, then you have to make sure that your server delivers the meta data for each video under its respective URL.